# dhtmlx scheduler and entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, scheduler, dhtmlx-scheduler

Hi I am using dhtmlx scheduler with mvc razor.

I have create the units tab. But i am not getting how to divide the events across different units. Here is my sample code.

```
Scheduler.InitialDate = DateTime.Now.Date;// the initial data of Scheduler   
       var unit = new UnitsView("Employee", "EmpID");//initializes the view
       var rooms = new List<object>(){
            new { key = "1", label = "Employee1"},
            new { key = "2", label = "Employee2"},
            new { key = "3", label = "Employee3"},
            new { key = "4", label = "Employee4"}
              };
          unit.AddOptions(rooms);

        Scheduler.Views.Add(unit);
```

I need to add the label from the database, I get the ID and display name through a stored procedure,Please help me displaying it in the scheduler unitsview.
I use entity database first in mvc3 razor

**Update:**

```
 var unit = new UnitsView("units", "resourcename");
            scheduler.Views.Add(unit);
              List<GetResourceOrderDisplay_Result> resourcedisplayname = new List<GetResourceOrderDisplay_Result>();
              resourcedisplayname = _scheduler.Getresorderdisplay();
            DashboardViewModel objDashboardViewModel = new DashboardViewModel();
             var options = new List<object>();
          //how to add key and label from the result i'm getting from resourcedisplayname?

            unit.AddOptions(options);
```

>

```
 public partial class GetResourceOrderDisplay_Result
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    }
```

model:

```
public class DashboardViewModel
    {


        //scheduler unitsview
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    }
```

this is where I get Id and display name from the storedprocedure

```
 public List<GetResourceOrderDisplay_Result> Getresorderdisplay()
        {
            List<GetResourceOrderDisplay_Result> oGetresorderdisplay = new List<GetResourceOrderDisplay_Result>();

            oGetresorderdisplay = dbContext.GetResourceOrderDisplay().ToList();

            return oGetresorderdisplay.ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > But i am not getting how to divide the events across different units

Second parameter of units view constructor specifies the property of the data item that holds the relation. In your code

```
var unit = new UnitsView("Employee", "EmpID");//initializes the view
var rooms = new List<object>(){
    new { key = "1", label = "Employee1"},
    new { key = "2", label = "Employee2"},
    new { key = "3", label = "Employee3"},
    new { key = "4", label = "Employee4"}
};
```

Scheduler will check value of eventObj.EmpID property of your events and will be placing events inside the columns with equal value of the 'key' property. Event with EventObj.EmpID == "2" will be placed inside the second column.

> I need to add the label from the database,

UnitsView has a public Label property

```
var unit = new UnitsView("Employee", "EmpID");
unit.Label = "label";
```

**UPDATE**

if you use model class with a different properties, you still can collect values for a units view with IEnumerable.Select :

```
var unit = new UnitsView("Employee", "EmpID");

List<GetResourceOrderDisplay_Result> resourcedisplayname = new List<GetResourceOrderDisplay_Result>();
resourcedisplayname = _scheduler.Getresorderdisplay();

unit.AddOptions(resourcedisplayname.Select(u => new {key=u.ID, label=u.DisplayName}));
```

Comment: Please check my update I'm getting the id and display name from a list, how to add that in unitview name?